# module 'numpy' has no attribute 'unionId'

Tags: python, numpy

upgraded/reinstalled numpy, still getting the same error as,

module 'numpy' has no attribute 'intersectId'
module 'numpy' has no attribute 'unionId'
module 'numpy' has no attribute 'setdiffId'

Comment: That's supposed to be a `1`. The digit before `2`. Not the capital version of `i`.

Comment: @Separius: Don't edit the bug out of the error messages.

Comment: user2357112 has already answered this, in future, it might be helpful to use the `dir()` function to debug these kinds of errors, like `dir(numpy)` shows `intersect1d` as a member of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the NumPy intersect1d module,  not intersectId. Given that you correctly installed Numpy, you can import/use it like this:

`import numpy as np
print(np.intersect1d([1, 3, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2, 1]))`

Which will give you:

```
array([1, 3])
```